# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'get' on VectorAssembler spark ML

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to follow the example discussed [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#vectorassembler) and I just copied the code into Zeppelin paragraph.

```
%pyspark
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors

dataset = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
[(0, 18, 1.0, Vectors.dense([0.0, 10.0, 0.5]), 1.0)],
["id", "hour", "mobile", "userFeatures", "clicked"])
print(type(dataset))
assembler = VectorAssembler(
inputCols=["hour", "mobile", "userFeatures"],
outputCol="features")
output = assembler.transform(dataset)
```

However, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark.py", line 164, in <module> 
    intp.setStatementsFinished(output.get(), False) 
  File "/home/zeppelin/zeppelin-0.5.5-incubating-bin-all/interpreter/spark/pyspark/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 749, in __getattr__ "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__, name)) 
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try changing

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
```

with

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
```